# Cannot connect to SMTP host in local XAMPP

Tags: php, smtp

I've been working on a project on my localhost to send an email through php but i keep getting the error :SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host. I'm using the PHPMailer and have gone through the troubleshooting but nothing seems to work. Here is the code:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

try {

  $mail->isSMTP();

  $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
  $mail->Host = 'smtp.sendgrid.com';
  $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
  $mail->Username = 'noreplyUser';
  $mail->Password = '';
  $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS; /ENCRYPTION_SMTPS;*/
  $mail->Port = 587; //25 - 465
  $mail->setFrom('example@mail.com', 'test');
  $mail->addAddress('example@mail.com');
  $mail->isHTML(true);
  $mail->Subject = 'test request';
  $mail->Body    = '';
  $mail->AltBody = '';

  $mail->send();
  echo 'Message has been sent';
} catch (Exception $e) {
  echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to disable firewall on your local machine. Then try different ports starting from 2525 or 465